# Set sessionStorage in JSONP results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to set `sessionStorage` using HTML5 in the result handler of an AJAX JSONP request. To explain this, lets say my AJAX is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('.dotted-list');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php?sub='+categories+'',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var landmark = '<a href="products.html"  data-transition="slidefade" onClick="sessionStorage.someKey = 'Something';">'
                + '<div class="sub-baners">'
                + '<img src='+item.aw_image_url+' >'
                + '</div>'
                + '</a>';
                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
```

As you can see I'm trying to set `sessionStorage` using an inline `onClick=""` but I know what I am doing is wrong because when I inspect the element in the browser instead of getting something like this:

```
 onClick="sessionStorage.someKey='Something';"
```

I get a very strange output which is messed up! something like this:

```
Something;' onClick="sessionStorage.someKey = "
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a wrong code, but you can fix this:

```
  onClick="sessionStorage.someKey = \'Something\';"
```

Look at the escaped single quotes.

However, is better if you remove the onclick in the html and write a listener in a javascript file that allows you to control better and with a correct syntax.